# DHL request xml parsing error ,code 111

Tags: magento-1.8, xml, php-5.4, dhl

It was all set a while ago,but got this error today.

Here is the debug log

```
2014-03-26T08:44:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [try-0] => Array
    (
        [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
            <GetQuote xmlns="">
                <Request>
                    <ServiceHeader>
                        <SiteID>AMPROSERVE</SiteID>
                        <Password>YourPwd</Password>
                    </ServiceHeader>
                </Request>
                <From>
                    <CountryCode>TW</CountryCode>
                    <Postalcode>42751</Postalcode>
                    <City>TANTZ</City>
                </From>
                <BkgDetails>
                    <PaymentCountryCode>TW</PaymentCountryCode>
                    <Date>2014-03-26</Date>
                    <ReadyTime>PT12H00M</ReadyTime>
                    <DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit>
                    <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
                    <Pieces xmlns=""/>
                    <PaymentAccountNumber>YorNumber</PaymentAccountNumber>
                </BkgDetails>
                <To>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <Postalcode>02139</Postalcode>
                    <City>Cambridge</City>
                </To>
            </GetQuote></p:DCTRequest>

        [from_cache] => 1
        [response] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <res:ErrorResponse xmlns:res='http://www.dhl.com' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation= 'http://www.dhl.com err-res.xsd'>
                    <Response>
                        <ServiceHeader>
                            <MessageTime>2014-03-26T08:44:16+00:00</MessageTime>
                            <SiteID>AMPROSERVE</SiteID>
                            <Password>AMPROSERVE</Password>
                        </ServiceHeader>
                        <Status>
                            <ActionStatus>Error</ActionStatus>
                            <Condition>
                                <ConditionCode>111</ConditionCode>
                                <ConditionData>Error in parsing request XML:Error: The
                                content of element type &quot;Pieces&quot; is
                                incomplete, it must match
                                &quot;(Piece,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?,Piece?)&quot;.
                                at line 2, column 658</ConditionData>
                            </Condition>
                        </Status>
                    </Response></res:ErrorResponse>
    )

    [__pid] => 770397
)
```

What's wrong with my request xml?

Comment: What was your fix for this? As I'm having similar issues?

Comment: @AndrewCaulfield I set the values as the [picture](http://i.imgur.com/bnLMls8.png) . You may have different error from me. Watch for the **ConditionData**  column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild stab in the dark here but it looks like you need to provide a valid `Pieces` section in your request.

Have a look at the `_makePieces` function to see what exactly is going wrong and how you can fix it.

Comment: Facing same issue how to manage in Magento 2?

Comment: Kindly help me, how can i solve DHL updates not save,, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/220467/57334

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and the reason was that the products had no set weight.