# DHL - Not Able to change Ship to Specific Countries and Ship to Applicable Countries

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, dhl

1) I can't able to `selected specific countries`, if i selected all countries except INDIA `half of the countries not choosing`, i mean not selected.

2) If i change Ship to Applicable Countries as `All allowed countries`  its not changing.

Screen Shot:

[image]

[image]

**Note : There is no error log.**

Comment: I am not able to understand your question

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Let me explain, if i select all countries, its not updates to select all countries.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Another eg, if i select Ship to Applicable Countries to All allowed countries its not saved, again and again Specific countries  selected by default, my update not working.

Comment: Change settings as individual store wish, its solve my error.

Answer (score 0):

If choose "All allowed countries" by default it will choose the all countries and the multiple select will be disable.